# How to fetch entities from database and lock corresponding database rows in Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible (and how) in Doctrine 2 to create a query with a `QueryBuilder` and acquire a write lock for each of the matching rows? `LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` can be used when fetching individual items with `EntityRepository->find()`, but I haven't been able to find such property for QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to call `setLockMode()` on the `Query` object.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->getQuery();

$query->setLockMode(LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

$results = $query->getResult();
```

The very last line of the [Transactions and Concurrency](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#pessimistic-locking) documentation page shows that `Query->setLockMode()` is supported. A bit hard to notice, but it's there... ;)